# Can I use typedef for an array length?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that I want to use to represent a generalized point on a bezier curve.  Right now it looks like this:

```
//BezierCurvePoint.h

class BezierCurvePoint
{
    int _pointDepth;
    double* _pointData;
    int _layerDepth;
    double* _layerData;

public:
    BezierCurvePoint(int pointDepth, int layerDepth = 0);

    //Lots of operator methods to make math easier
}


//BezierCurvePoint.cpp

BezierCurvePoint::BezierCurvePoint(int pointDepth, int layerDepth) :
    _pointDepth(pointDepth),
    _layerDepth(layerDepth)
{
    _pointData = pointDepth ? new double[pointDepth] : nullptr;
    _layerData = layerDepth ? new double[layerDepth] : nullptr;
}
```

The _pointData represents the coordinates for the point and the _layerData is some extra information I want to store per point such as line width and tilt. Unfortunately, I'm also creating and deleting lots of tiny arrays.

I would like to be able to create variations on this point type. So I would have one version with pointDepth = 2 and layerDepth = 1, and another with pointDepth = 3 and layerDepth = 2. I have some generic methods that will work so long as they know the depths of the different arrays

When I use my points in a single curve, they're all going to have the same pointDepth and layerDepth, it would be useful if I could figure out a typedef (or some other refinement) of this more general case so that I'm using fixed length arrays instead of allocating them.  It would also make debugging easier.

I don't want to use templates since I have some lengthy functions that are defined in the .cpp which I'd prefer to keep out of the header.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If they have fixed length and depth, why not use `std::array`?

Comment: I would like to be able to create variations on this point type.  So I could have one version with pointDepth = 2 and layerDepth = 1, and another with pointDepth = 3 and layerDepth = 2.  I have some generic methods that will work so long as they know the depths of the different arrays.

Comment: Maybe you can update the question to clarify that.

Comment: It sounds like you still want `std::array`, and to make the point and layer depths template parameters of `BezierCurvePoint`.

Comment: Maybe "typedef double(PointData)[2];"?